# Failed to locate nib in stylus file

Tags: nib, stylus

I am trying to use Nib CSS3 extensions in stylus. Installed stylus and nib (tried local & global `-g`). But none works, when I do

```
stylus styles.styl > build/styles.css

# styles.styl
@import "nib"
```

I get

```
/usr/lib/node_modules/stylus/bin/stylus:502
              throw err;
                    ^
Error: styles.styl:1
 > 1| @import "nib"
   2| 
   3| body 
   4|   background: linear-gradient(top, white, black)

failed to locate @import file nib.styl

    at Evaluator.visitImport (/usr/lib/node_modules/stylus/lib/visitor/evaluator.js:659:21)
    at Evaluator.Visitor.visit (/usr/lib/node_modules/stylus/lib/visitor/index.js:28:40)
    at Evaluator.visit (/usr/lib/node_modules/stylus/lib/visitor/evaluator.js:75:18)
    at Evaluator.visitRoot (/usr/lib/node_modules/stylus/lib/visitor/evaluator.js:521:27)
    at Evaluator.Visitor.visit (/usr/lib/node_modules/stylus/lib/visitor/index.js:28:40)
    at Evaluator.visit (/usr/lib/node_modules/stylus/lib/visitor/evaluator.js:75:18)
    at Evaluator.evaluate (/usr/lib/node_modules/stylus/lib/visitor/evaluator.js:150:15)
    at Renderer.render (/usr/lib/node_modules/stylus/lib/renderer.js:69:26)
    at /usr/lib/node_modules/stylus/bin/stylus:496:15
    at fs.readFile (fs.js:176:14)
```

Comment: whats the command you're running?

Comment: @JonathanOng, `stylus styles.styl > build/styles.css`

Comment: try `stylus -u nib stylus.styl -o build/`. i have issues with using stdin/out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes I think I missed out the `-u` flag as @Jonathan pointed out

Answer (score 0):

the complete line of code for automatic transpilation would be :

```
stylus -w -u nib test.styl -o test.css
```